# People API searchContacts using google people service

Tags: google-people-api

I have tried adding a new contact using Google People API with PHP client people service and it worked fine. I have used following code,

```
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);
$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();
$name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
$name->setGivenName($_name);
$person->setNames($name);
$phone1 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_PhoneNumber();   
$phone1->setValue($_phone);
$phone1->setType('home');
$person->setPhoneNumbers($phone1);
$exe = $service->people->createContact($person)->execute;
```

Now I want to check if particular email already exists so tried searchContacts method of API. It works fine in API explorer.
ref:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts

But when have tried with following code,

```
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);
$optParams = array('query'=>$_email,'pageSize' => 10, 'readMask' => 'emailAddresses', 'key'=>'XXXX');
try{
    $rslt = $service->people->searchContacts($optParams);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

i am getting following error,

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Google_Service_PeopleService_Resource_People::searchContacts()

Looking at the error i am sure that the way to call the method is wrong. I have searched but not able to get proper documentation in guiding in that direction.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `key` come from? Does not seem to be a valid parameter for the method [searchContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts).

Comment: If i removed key it does not make any difference. I just tried various combination (In API explorer HTTP json it is one of parameter). Anyways the error says "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_PeopleService_Resource_People::searchContacts()" so it is problem with method and not with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we cannot call searchContacts using people service object so i have used curl json to get it worked. I have used following code if anyone needs.

```
$url_parameters = array('query'=>$_email,'pageSize' => 10, 'readMask' => 'names,phoneNumbers,emailAddresses,organizations', 'key'=>'XXXXX');

$url_calendars = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?'. http_build_query($url_parameters);

$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_calendars);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); 
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      
if($http_code != 200) 
    throw new Exception('Error : Failed to search contact');

return $data;
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why or where, but for sure you can use searchContacts from PeopleService. Maybe you where in the middle of a transition. It should work. What I mean, is that i am right now coding this and searchContact just works, with or without google-api-client library.